# Piecewise-$C^k$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

A function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called piecewise-$\mathcal{C}^k$ if

1. There is a partition $\{ x_i \}_{i=0}^\infty $ with $x_0=0$ and $x_{i+1}>x_i$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$ on each $\left( x_i,x_{i+1} \right)$.

Or

2. $f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function except at a subset of $\mathbb{R}_+$ with zero Lebesgue measure.

Are these definitions correct and also, equivalent? (Honestly, I don't have a solid background on Lebesgue measure theory so I'm not sure about the second definition)

Comment: The "finte partition" was a mistake

Answer (score 2):

They're not correct and also not equivalent. (1) is close. In fact $f$ is piecewise $C^k$ if there is a partition such that $f$ is $C^k$ on each $(x_j,x_{j+1})$, *and* the $k$-th derivative $f^{(k)}$ has one-sided limits at each endpoint (which implies that $f^{(j)}$ also has one-sided limits for $0\le j < k$).

If we were talking about a bounded interval $(a,b)$ that would be a finite  partition. For $(0,\infty)$ it could also be an infinite partition as long as $x_j<x_{j+1}$ and $x_j\to\infty$.

On the other hand, it's not clear to me what (2) even *means*! Say $m(E)=0$; what does it *mean* to say $f$ is $C^k$ on $\Bbb R\setminus E$? If $E$ is *closed* this is clear...

Comment: Can we say $C^k$ almost everywhere?

Comment: What does "$C^k$ almost everywhere" _mean_, exactly? Saying $f>2$ almost everywhere makes sense because being greater than $2$ is a pointwise property; $f$ is greater than $2$ at $x$ if $f(x)>2$. If we're going to assign a meaning to "$f$ is $C^k$  at $x$" it's going to require that $f$ be at least $C^{k-1}$ in some _neighborhood of_ $x$...